# Is there any method to remove this: "config.php?username=++psw&Text=psw&submit=send?" after clicking a submit button and just stay in the page?

Tags: php, html

when I click on the submit button in my form php performs its task but instead of staying on the page (or at most reloading it) it sends me to the same url but with "/config.php?username=technologies.%0D%0A++&submit = Send "
is there any way to make it do its job when I hit the Enter button and stay on the page or reload it?

if you don't understand go directly to the page and try to write in the two boxes, and press enter, is there any way to remove that page?

http://serversamuel.altervista.org/1aoin/italiano/php/Commentinuovo.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>

html { background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #79C7C5 40%, #F9FBFF 100%);
}
input {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;    
    
}

input {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.box{background-color: White;
  width: 300px;
  border: 15px solid white;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: left;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:2px;
  height:70px;
  
  }
  .write{
  background-color: White;
  width: 300px;
  height:60%;
  border: px solid  white;
padding:50px;
  object-position: right top;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:2px;
  position:absolute;
  right:1px;
  top:1px;
  }
 p{position:relative;
 text-align:left;
 margin-top:-50px;
 
 }
 
 .comment{
 height:90px;
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  .textarea1 { height: 20px; margin-left:25%;row:1;resize: none;overflow:hidden;text-align:left;padding-left:0;
padding-top:-5em;
padding-bottom:0.4em;
padding-right: 0.4em;margin-left: auto;   display: block;
    margin-right: auto;top:10%;}
  
  
  
  .text{resize: none;overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:70%;margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;}
    

/* waves */
.ocean {
  height:40px; /* change the height of the waves here */
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wave {
  background: url("http://serversamuel.altervista.org/prototipi/waves/wave.svg");
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: wave 10s -3s linear infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0.8;

}

.wave:nth-of-type(2) {
  bottom: 0;

  animation: wave 18s linear reverse infinite;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.wave:nth-of-type(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wave 20s -1s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

@keyframes wave {
    0% {transform: translateX(0);}
    50% {transform: translateX(-25%);}
    100% {transform: translateX(-50%);}
}


</style>

<?php
    include("commentinuovo.php");
?>




















 <form action="config.php">
<div class="write">

<textarea class="textarea1"  maxlength="50"  width="90px" height="80%" row="1" placeholder="Name" name="username"  >
  </textarea>
  <br><br>
  <textarea class="text" name="Text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Inserisci qui il tuo commento"   >
textt
  </textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
  <div class="ocean">
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
</div>
</div> 
</form> 
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default method for a `<form>` is GET, in which key/value pairs for the form values are part of the query string.

More commonly, you can use POST:

```
<form method="POST" action="config.php">
```

This will put the key/value pairs in the request body (I believe the default content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Two important things to note would be:

1. Server-side code would have to look for the information in the right place, as it will no longer be part of the query string.  *Ideally* this just means that if you currently use the `$_GET` array to read form values, you'll instead need to use the `$_POST` array.
2. Even though the values aren't on the URL query string, they **are** still visible to the user.  Please do not assume that this form posting method applies any security at all.

---

As an aside...

> do its job when I hit the Enter button and stay on the page or reload it

It's important to understand how HTTP requests are working in this context.  In **both** cases (using GET with values in the query string or using POST with values in the request body) the user is being directed to a new page.  The only difference is the request being sent to the server to navigate to that page.

That "new page" may indeed be the same page as before, at least visually.  But as far as the browser is concerned it was retrived by an entirely new and unrelated HTTP request.  And if you ever "reload" that page, it will *replay that same request*.

For example, if you make a POST request with information that gets inserted into a database, and then "reload", the same request is made again and a new record is inserted into the database.  A common way to avoid this is to not display a page in response to such a request.  Instead, you'd perform the operation (insert into the database, for example) and then redirect the user back to the page.  A redirect produces a separte GET request, which the user can "reload" over and over without consequence.

There is a technique for performing these kinds of operations in the background and not navigating to a new page at all.  The technology you'd be looking for in that case is called AJAX.  There are many examples and tutorials to get you started with that, if that is your goal.